# Is moving from the role "software engineer" to "Android Developer" considered as a career path/ job degradation?

Tags: software-industry, job-offer, job-change, software-development, career-switch

I am currently working as a junior software engineer, engaging in multiple fields including Java, Android and web programming. Recently I got a job offer for an "Android Developer" with a better package than my existing one. But the language I will be using is Kotlin.

I'm having doubts whether to take it or not since it might affect my future career & position?

Would like to hear some ideas regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the Workplace. You post seems to me rather asking for personal career advice. Unfortunately we can´t provide such advice in this format. For more information see the [help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the actual names but the content of your new activities. Do you want to work with Kotlin? (I write it like you don't like it).

Comment: Titles don't matter much. You can do some market research to determine what sort of demand there is for Android and/or Kotlin devs, and how fast that demand is growing. But the more important question might be whether this supports your planned career path (do you *want* to be an Android / Kotlin dev? If not, would you be learning skills transferable to what you want to be doing in this role?).

Comment: It's just a job title.  Most of the time these are specific to your company.  Instead, concentrate on your skill development.

Comment: *"I'm having doubts whether to take it or not since it might affect my future career & position?"* Can't really answer that unless you tell us what you want your "future career" to be.

Comment: Some thoughts, as an android (Java) developer, this year I made the "jump" to Kotlin and found it to be quite a good choice. Having Java experience made the switch easier. I am now a Kotlin lover

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is moving from the role “software engineer” to “Android Developer”
>   considered as a career path/ job degradation?

**No.** The title change is unimportant.

You just happen to be moving from a more general title "Junior Software Engineer" to a more specific title of "Android Developer".

What you do in those roles if far more important.

Comment: *What you do in those roles if far more important.*  This is indeed the heart of the matter.  Glad to see you active sir!